# Our users keep getting Payment Declined error when making Android in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, google-developers-console, google-play-billing

We just published our app on Google Play Store but all IAP attempts that use any  payment method, except Test Cards, always gets "Error: Transaction was declined" error.
[transaction-declined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buPVk.jpg)

When we check the Order ID on PlayStore Console, the log shown: "There was an issue charging the user's payment method".
[console-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgRgm.jpg).

Here are few more information about our situation:

1/ We are using Google Library Billing v3

2/ The IAP worked fine when we test with our Test Cards, but when switching to Public version and try a real payment method, it doesn't work (we tried Credit card, e-Wallet.., nothing worked).

3/ When we check the log, error code was: PurchasesUpdatedListener -> response code = ERROR

4/ We tried to re-create the In-app products, remove and re-upload the packages, but still the same: Test cards work, real payment method doesn't.

Can someone let me know if we missed any setup? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you acknowledging the purchase? Google will refund any purchase that isn't acknowledged in 3 days

Comment: HI! I have the same issue. Have you solved your problem?